# Spotlight in Mavericks does not search Tags - how to enable?

Tags: macos, spotlight, finder-tag

I have defined a couple of tags in Mavericks. If I search inside Finder, tags work as expected:

It recognizes that "Firma" is a tag.

[image]

If I select it and press enter, it turns into "Tag:Firma".

[image]

However if I do the same in the global search (CMD+SPACE), it seems to have no idea about tags:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this or is it a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeated your steps in renaming one of my Tags.

My MBA with 10.9.2 does exactly the same as yours.

The Spotlight does following:

By entering the Tag name it sorts and shows the actually tagged files first in the search window.

So it knows those files were tagged by that tag.

Comment: That seems to be true, yes. But I thought it used to show the tag explicitly. Hmm...seems like my memory is playing tricks on me.

Comment: Try giving your Tag a unique names (Like "-Firma-") or simular giving the Search a chance to differentiate.

Comment: You are right. It searches for the tags but does not display it like in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Tags have never worked that way for me. I don't know if they should, but they work for me if I prefix the tag with `tag:` like this:

```
tag:Firma
```

Comment: If I do that, the returned result list is empty.

Comment: @Krumelur Same here and as detailed in [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108076/how-to-enable-missing-tag-search-in-spotlight). Seems to be a bug or a removed feature.